# Reply with same source ip address as incoming?

Tags: linux, networking, ip, snmp

I have a system with two different ip addresses on same interface. Both IPs are connected to the same network. One of them is set as the default route; a side effect of this is that if a packet comes in on the non-default-route IP, the reply is sent back through the default route interface. Is there a way to solve this?
What i expect is that response is sent from same IP address as source for which request was came.

Output of `ip address`

```
`5: eth-access: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 96:52:79:33:7a:90 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.12/28 scope global eth-access
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.0.13/28 scope global secondary eth-access
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever `
```

Here is the SNMP request details for which wrong source IP is used. Request comes to ip "13" but answer comes from "12":

```
17:55:24.692149 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 63, id 35960, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 76)
    192.168.0.116.55421 > 192.168.0.13.161:  { SNMPv2c C="Test" { GetNextRequest(26) R=361171477  .1.3.6.1.2.1.1 } }
17:55:24.693519 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 22807, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 133)
    192.168.0.12.161 > 192.168.0.116.55421:  { SNMPv2c C="Test" { GetResponse(83) R=361171477  .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0="SunOS Node1 5.11 pn-tpOS-2.6.1-2060112460 i86pc" } }
```

To solve this i have created separate ip table for "13" ip. But it did not solve the issue.

```
echo 252 snmp >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
ip rule add from 192.168.0.13 table snmp
ip route add default via 1192.168.0.1 dev eth-access src 192.168.0.13 table snmp
ip route add 192.168.0.0/28 dev eth-access src 192.168.0.13 table snmp
```

Here is the output from system:

```
# ip rule list
0:      from all lookup local
32765:  from 192.168.0.13 lookup snmp
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default

# ip route list table snmp
default via 192.168.0.1 dev eth-access  src 192.168.0.13
192.168.0.0/28 dev eth-access  scope link  src 192.168.0.13
```

Is there any way to ensure that same source ip address is used as came in request. In case we have two IPs from same subnet on one interface.

EDIT: For Clarification:
I need to ensure that this server replies to request with same source IP as the destination IP of request. i.e. if request comes for destination IP 192.168.0.13 then response should be with source IP 192.168.0.13. Currently response to SNMP requests is going with IP address 192.168.0.12 as source IP when request comes for IP address 192.168.0.13.

EDIT: Solution
Finally, i realized that tool for which i was doing this testing was able to accept this response.
For testing i was using SNMPwalk command from another server which was not accepting the response. ( I assume because of different source address).
But the actual SNMP tool seems to be more generous and accepted the response without any changes at myside.
I am not sure how this works but thought of sharing this. 
Thank you all of you for your help.

Comment: I am confused as to what you need but If I am understanding what you are saying you want to NAT the source address to what you want?

Comment: @madmanali93, I need to ensure that this server replies to request with same source IP as the destination IP of request. i.e. if request comes for destination IP 192.168.0.13 then response should be with source IP 192.168.0.13. Currently response to SNMP requests is going with IP address 192.168.0.12 as source IP.

Comment: You could try restricting the snmpd server to listen only on one IP address, `snmpd udp:192.168.0.13`. If that works, then perhaps run a second snmpd with the other address.